# How to use the 'og' (Open Graph) meta tag for Facebook share

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta

Facebook fetches all pictures from my site.

I want to share only one picture which is on that page.

I heard about the `og` meta tag, but I don't know how to put it.

Answer (score 365):

Use:

```html
<!-- For Google -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="copyright" content="" />
<meta name="application-name" content="" />

<!-- For Facebook -->
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />

<!-- For Twitter -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
```

Fill the content =" ... " according to the content of your page.

For more information, visit *[18 Meta Tags Every Webpage Should Have in 2013](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013/)*.

Comment: Do you know if the `author` tag should have the author name, or a link to a profile URL?

Comment: I think both is possible. If you want your profile image at the left side of your post at the google search page, you should provide the link to your google+ profile.

Comment: meta tag `author` means author of website or author of current article( example in usage on blog article )?

Comment: Is this a good execution? Will Google/Facebook/Twitter find no errors with this?

Comment: 1) Facebook will read the <meta name="author"> tag and display it in the preview when someone shares a page 
2) Facebook now has support for <meta property="article:author"> (details at http://giannopoulos.net/2015/06/20/how-to-add-authorship-information-for-facebook-pinterest-and-google-on-your-blog/) and will display a link to your Facebook profile (if you actually put a link to it in article:author) 
3) Google now looks for rich data in the form of what it calls "Rich Snippets" (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/)

Comment: Google [no longer uses the `keywords` tag](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).

Comment: Is there a specific order to follow such as title before description?

Answer (score 43):

Facebook uses what's called the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) to decide what things to display when you share a link. The OGP looks at your page and tries to decide what content to show. We can lend a hand and actually **tell** Facebook what to take from our page.

**The way we do that is with `og:meta` tags.**

The tags look something like this -

```
  <meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html">
```

You'll need to place these or similar meta tags in the `<head>` of your HTML file. Don't forget to substitute the values for your own!

For more information you can read all about how Facebook uses these meta tags in their documentation. Here is one of the tutorials from there -  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

---

Facebook gives us a great little tool to help us when dealing with these meta tags - you can use the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see how Facebook sees your URL, and it'll even tell you if there are problems with it.

One thing to note here is that every time you make a change to the meta tags, you'll need to feed the URL through the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) again so that Facebook will clear all the data that is cached on their servers about your URL.

Comment: I am seeing html tags in my description, do you know how to get around this?

Answer (score 28):

I built a tool for meta generation. It pre-configures entries for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter, and you can use it free here: http://www.groovymeta.com

To answer the question a bit more, `OG` tags (Open Graph) tags work similarly to meta tags, and should be placed in the HEAD section of your HTML file. See [Facebook's best practises](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) for more information on how to use OG tags effectively.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad I have expanded on my answer accordingly.

Comment: Link broken, unfortunately!