# How to pass a parameter like title, summary and image in a Facebook sharer URL

Tags: php, html, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-sharer

**Question:**

I need to pass my content like title, summary and image in a Facebook sharer URL like this:

```
 <a id="button"
    href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
    s=100
    &p[url]=http://myurl.com/overview/sap-talent
    &p[images][0]=http://myurl/images/my_image.png
    &p[title]=mytitle
    &p[summary]=containsummary">
```

The problem is it's automatically getting some content from the above mentioned URL (http://myurl.com/overview/sap-talent), and I don't know where my title and summary data are gone. Is there another way to share my custom title, summary and image via `facebooksharer.php`?

Comment: [How to use og meta tags for facebook share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share) Could be use.

Comment: @dbh I used og meta tag but still title,summary and image what im trying to pass is not showing ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like Facebook disabled passing parameters to the sharer.

> We have changed the behavior of the sharer plugin to be consistent with other plugins and features on our platform.
>
> The sharer will no longer accept custom parameters and facebook will pull the information that is being displayed in the preview the same way that it would appear on facebook as a post from the url OG meta tags.

Here's the URL to the post: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/

Comment: Read the rest of the comments...that post was just a opinion.

Answer (score 26):

The only parameter you need right now is `?u=<YOUR_URL>`. All other data will be fetched from page or (better) from your open graph meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

[Example & description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

You can test your page for accordance in [the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Comment: Even if the data will be fetched from the page it is still better to send the parameters if they are easily accessible, a busy website doesn't need anymore requests than it already has :)

Comment: @Bodokh: on the contrary. You're sending parameters that will be ignored by Facebook because it fetches them from the meta tags. Sending and receiving and then ignoring these URL parameters takes some bandwidth and CPU cycles. Not that it makes any difference, compared to watching a cat video.

Answer (score 19):

This works at the moment (Oct. 2016), but I can't guarantee how long it will last:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?caption=[caption]&description=[description]&u=[website]&picture=[image-url]
```

Comment: Will this work after july 10th? Because after using this method for a long time with no issues, I noticed that "sometimes" the image is not showing in the share dialog, but the image will be showed when posted in the wall. Looks like there is some kind of timeout and in case the image has not been loaded (or processed by fb) before the timeout, the image holder will be empty. But the weirdest issue of all, is that in some cases, FB is making up an OG image from the content of the site.

Comment: The `description` and `caption` parameters seem to have no effect, but `u` still works.

Answer (score 15):

It seems that the only parameter that allows you to inject custom text is the "quote".

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=THE_URL&quote=THE_CUSTOM_TEXT
```

Comment: Woot! This one still works!

Comment: Woot! This one doesn't work anymore!

Comment: &display=popup or &display=page works

Answer (score 5):

On the Developers bugs Facebook site, the last answer about that (`parameters with sharer.php`), makes me believe it was a bug that was going to be resolved. Am I right?

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/

> Ibrahim Faour ·  · Facebook Platform Team
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience. We aim to update our external reports
>   as soon as we get a resolution on issues. I do understand that
>   sometimes the answer provided may not be satisfying, but we are eager
>   to keep our platform as stable and efficient as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've used the below before, and it has worked. It isn't very pretty, but you can alter it to suit your needs.

The following JavaScript function grabs the `location.href` & `document.title` for the sharer, and you can ultimately change these.

```
function fbs_click() {
        u=location.href;
        t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
                'sharer',
                'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

            return false;
        }
```

Usage:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">
    Share on Facebook
</a>
```

It looks like this is what you could possibly be looking for: [Facebook sharer title / desc....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12799020/2518525)

Answer (score 0):

`&display=popup` versus `&display=page` changes the layout. Other than that, only the url can be passed using `u=https://developers.facebook.com`.
`display` parameter is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/