# Facebook share url: how to insert custom text at the post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I believe that the answser is simple, but I can't find any useful updated answer.

With Facebook you can easily share a link using this url:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://stackoverflow.com

And with Twitter, you can easily share a tweet using this other format:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello%20this%20is%20a%20tweet

(You can click on the links to see the result)

---

The thing is, in twitter you can see that I can specify the text of the post directly in the url. But I don't know how to do this on Facebook.

There's a way to do this, with Facebook? I don't want that the user share any URL, but a post with a default text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Facebook disabled passing parameters to the sharer.see this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652041/how-to-pass-parameter-like-title-summary-and-image-in-facebook-sharer-url)

Comment: _“I don't want that the user share any URL, but a post with a default text”_ – that is not even allowed by Facebook. The message part of any post has to be user generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

Comment: @CBroe and can I open the dialog without an url? I don't want to share any url, I just want gave the user a quick way to share a message

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook provides these dialogs for the purpose of sharing content, as in URLs to other sites. There is no dialog for simply posting a status – that’s what the official Facebook UI is for.