# Create a pre-typed post with facebook using a URL (query) only

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-share

Is there a way to create a facebook post without installing their SDK and creating an app?

Just like twitter where you can pre-create a post if the user clicked:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Checkout this`!&url=https://example.com
```

So basically my app WILL NOT HANDLE the posting it self, we just pre-set the text that can be posted and open it on facebook.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog But you won’t be able to specify the message to share, Facebook does not allow that. At most you will be able to _suggest_ a quote and a hastag, but the user has the option to remove both, before they make the share.

Comment: The old `sharer.php` also still works, but you won’t be able to specify any of the additional parameters such as title, description and thumbnail any more, only the URL to share itself. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22652041/1427878

Comment: I guess that'll work for now, opening them on a new tab looks weird tho, I need to create a pop-up to "fix" the layout (which is bad UX if you're opp is a desktop app created from electron because by default the user is in logout state)