# Facebook App Creation related questions

Tags: facebook, dns, share

Good afternoon and happy new year!

I have a web site, whose URL is http://www.høly.com

The user will type something in the "type here & share" textbox and, when he clicks the Facebook logo, something will be shared to their Facebook timeline via an app.
1) I'm using Mozilla Firefox on Windows 8.1 and some users reported that Facebook sharing doesn't work on Mac OS X. It works for me though. The app is not sandboxed. I would like to know what is going on and how I can fix this.
2) Whenever someone shares my URL on Facebook (via copy-paste, not the app), I want it to have a specific image and a description. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: facebook plugins works on all browser, so there must be a javascript error in you code that prevents the execution of facebook script. 2. You can use og meta tags as described here
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share)