# Linking from facebook feed - invalid UTF-8 characters

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have a page set up with `charset="utf-8"`. 
On the page, characters like `æ`, `ø`, and `å` works fine, but when putting the link into the facebook feed, the characters are invalid, displaying only as a `?` on an black background.

Is this facebooks fault, or mine?

EDIT: here is an image: (see the ? in there)

[image]

Comment: What does that mean exactly, "putting the link into the Facebook feed"? Be more detailed about what you're doing and how you're doing it.

Comment: @deceze ok, I've added an image.

Comment: @kjelelokk is that content that shows part of the title, or part of the [Facebook meta tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share)? Perhaps the body content is valid UTF-8, but the title is not? What does https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug show?