# Change photo for facebook like pop up window

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-like, photo

Just add Facebook like button into my website. After clicking it, a window pop up to let user input comments and with the text content from my website. There is no problem for it after I input correct site URL. However, the photo in the pop up windows is still the default one (like a sun). How do I replace it with the photo of the logo of my website?

Comment: Use fb og: tags in the header. Read this post. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share

Answer (score 0):

Add **og** tags to your url. Here's the [doumentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted-creating) for the same.

You just have to add some meta-tags:

```
<meta property="og:title"           content="{title}" /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="{img_url}" /> 
<meta property="og:description"     content="{description}" /> 
<meta property="og:caption"         content="{caption}" />
```

and so on..

You can also check if the `og:tags` are read by facebook properly or not in [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), just put your url in there and facebook will show you the tags or show errors if any.