# HTML - Individual meta tag data for each page

Tags: html, facebook, yii, metadata, meta-tags

would like to as if is there such a thing that I can assign/update the meta tag data for each page? Noted that I have read meta tag must be put in the `<head>` tag so how should I design my code? This is what i wanted to achieve:

```
page1.php
<meta name="description" content="Page 1">
<meta name="author" content="owner 1">

page 2.php
<meta name="description" content="Page 2">
<meta name="author" content="owner 2">
```

And also how should I point to the relevant images when the facebook share link query? Like this:

[image: FB Share]

Hopefully someone could give me some guides. Thank you

Comment: What framework (MVC or CMS), or templating system are you using?

Comment: @DavidT I am using Yii framework

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that particular frameworks syntax/file structure, but have added the tag for you to bring in some Yii developers. Though I think you need `og:` metatags for use with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Action` add this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('Page 1', 'description');
```

Before redering your page. For more information see [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerMetaTag-detail)

About facebook meta tags, you can look [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share).

The Facebook uses `The Open Graph` meta tags, so see the [specs](http://ogp.me/) to more information about it.

Comment: Would like to check with you for like `<meta property="og:image" content="" />` and `<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />` the image does it only accept 1 image link or i can add more to it?

Comment: @KennyYap I don't really know how people do it, because the [specs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects) says:
`Each URL can only be a single object`. If you have a website to test, you can validate [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object)

Comment: @KennyYap See this [article](http://ogp.me/#array), will help you with the `og: meta tags`. This article have the specs from Open Graph(aka og), and there are many informations that will help you.