# How do I remove/edit the metadata description of my website? It overrides the one I have in index.html

Tags: html, web

I type out my website url in facebook to send to someone or post somewhere and the link appears below. And in that link, I get my website name, thumbnail and a description. How do I edit that description? I have a meta data description in my index.html file but this one overrides that. I am using a website template and this description is by someone who has created the template. How do I edit it? Is it hidden?

Comment: See this for proper facebook description tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-og-meta-tag-for-facebook-share  as far as your comment about someone else created the template, that is not anything anyone on here can answer.  You need to contact the person that created the template to find out if you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="description" content="this is my websites description! hi google!">`