# how to set image in my websites link using meta tags

Tags: html, web

My website is created from pure coding(no wordpress)
so i want to display a image with my websites link when it is share on social media
so please help me

Comment: Hi, can you please add more description about the problem and what did you try to solve it.

Comment: like when we send someone link of youtube video or instagram account you will there will be img show so how do i show image when my website link is shared

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the 'og' (Open Graph) meta tag for Facebook share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616697/how-to-use-the-og-open-graph-meta-tag-for-facebook-share)

Comment: yeah!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set a Open Graph Image.
Add within `<head></head>`:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://domain.tld/image.jpg">
```

The image should have at least a width of 1200 pixel.
The aspect ratio supposed to be 1:1 or 1.91:1.

Comment: this is working on all pages of my site except the main domain page I don't know why like title and description is changing but the image isn't coming (i comes in Instagram but not in WhatsApp)

Comment: Maybe it's a cache thing. And after a quick search I found some hints that WhatsApp doesn't like to large file sizes: with less than 300 KB you should be safe.